# python PIL YCbCr support

Tags: python, crash, python-imaging-library, yuv

Trying to create an PIL image in YCbCr mode crashes even a fresh python/PIL installation from synaptic in my ubuntu 11.04

```
wim@wim-ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Image
>>> Image.VERSION
'1.1.7'
>>> Image.new('YCbCr', (640,480))
*** buffer overflow detected ***: python terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7f4a35e4a1d7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xfd0f0)[0x7f4a35e490f0]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so(ImagingNewPrologueSubtype+0x97)[0x7f4a34bfb257]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so(ImagingNewBlock+0xb)[0x7f4a34bfb78b]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so(ImagingNew+0x4c)[0x7f4a34bfb86c]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so(+0xfd22)[0x7f4a34bddd22]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x361)[0x4965f1]
python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x145)[0x49d325]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x802)[0x496a92]
python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x145)[0x49d325]
python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x4ecb02]
python[0x4fdc74]
python(PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags+0x1e2)[0x42cd9e]
python(PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags+0xc0)[0x42cebd]
python(PyRun_AnyFileExFlags+0x39)[0x42d2e1]
python(Py_Main+0xac9)[0x418c9e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xff)[0x7f4a35d6aeff]
python[0x4c62b1]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0062f000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1049585                            /usr/bin/python2.7
0082e000-0082f000 r--p 0022e000 08:21 1049585                            /usr/bin/python2.7
0082f000-00897000 rw-p 0022f000 08:21 1049585                            /usr/bin/python2.7
00897000-008a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01f0a000-021a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f4a34794000-7f4a347a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 659235                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4a347a9000-7f4a349a8000 ---p 00015000 08:21 659235                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4a349a8000-7f4a349a9000 r--p 00014000 08:21 659235                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4a349a9000-7f4a349aa000 rw-p 00015000 08:21 659235                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4a349aa000-7f4a349cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1057568                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
7f4a349cd000-7f4a34bcc000 ---p 00023000 08:21 1057568                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
7f4a34bcc000-7f4a34bcd000 r--p 00022000 08:21 1057568                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
7f4a34bcd000-7f4a34bce000 rw-p 00023000 08:21 1057568                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
7f4a34bce000-7f4a34c0b000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1312337                    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
7f4a34c0b000-7f4a34e0b000 ---p 0003d000 08:21 1312337                    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
7f4a34e0b000-7f4a34e0e000 r--p 0003d000 08:21 1312337                    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
7f4a34e0e000-7f4a34e11000 rw-p 00040000 08:21 1312337                    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
7f4a34e11000-7f4a34e30000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1316665                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
7f4a34e30000-7f4a3502f000 ---p 0001f000 08:21 1316665                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
7f4a3502f000-7f4a35030000 r--p 0001e000 08:21 1316665                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
7f4a35030000-7f4a35034000 rw-p 0001f000 08:21 1316665                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
7f4a35034000-7f4a35035000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4a35035000-7f4a35075000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 655419                     /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
7f4a35075000-7f4a35274000 ---p 00040000 08:21 655419                     /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
7f4a35274000-7f4a35278000 r--p 0003f000 08:21 655419                     /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
7f4a35278000-7f4a35279000 rw-p 00043000 08:21 655419                     /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
7f4a35279000-7f4a352b2000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 655450                     /lib/libreadline.so.6.2
7f4a352b2000-7f4a354b2000 ---p 00039000 08:21 655450                     /lib/libreadline.so.6.2
7f4a354b2000-7f4a354b4000 r--p 00039000 08:21 655450                     /lib/libreadline.so.6.2
7f4a354b4000-7f4a354ba000 rw-p 0003b000 08:21 655450                     /lib/libreadline.so.6.2
7f4a354ba000-7f4a354bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4a354bb000-7f4a354c0000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1316693                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
7f4a354c0000-7f4a356bf000 ---p 00005000 08:21 1316693                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
7f4a356bf000-7f4a356c0000 r--p 00004000 08:21 1316693                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
7f4a356c0000-7f4a356c2000 rw-p 00005000 08:21 1316693                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
7f4a356c2000-7f4a35d4c000 r--p 00000000 08:21 1055991                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f4a35d4c000-7f4a35ed6000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 659207                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f4a35ed6000-7f4a360d5000 ---p 0018a000 08:21 659207                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f4a360d5000-7f4a360d9000 r--p 00189000 08:21 659207                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f4a360d9000-7f4a360da000 rw-p 0018d000 08:21 659207                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f4a360da000-7f4a360e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4a360e0000-7f4a36164000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 659244                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f4a36164000-7f4a36363000 ---p 00084000 08:21 659244                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f4a36363000-7f4a36364000 r--p 00083000 08:21 659244                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f4a36364000-7f4a36365000 rw-p 00084000 08:21 659244                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f4a36365000-7f4a3637c000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 659290                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7f4a3637c000-7f4a3657b000 ---p 00017000 08:21 659290                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7f4a3657b000-7f4a3657c000 r--p 00016000 08:21 659290                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7f4a3657c000-7f4a3657d000 rw-p 00017000 08:21 659290                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7f4a3657d000-7f4a366e3000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 655398                     /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
7f4a366e3000-7f4a368e3000 ---p 00166000 08:21 655398                     /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
7f4a368e3000-7f4a368f0000 r--p 00166000 08:21 655398                     /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
7f4a368f0000-7f4a36909000 rw-p 00173000 08:21 655398                     /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
7f4a36909000-7f4a3690c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4a3690c000-7f4a36958000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 655454                     /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8Aborted
wim@wim-ubuntu:~$
```

I've tried

```
find /usr -name Image.py | xargs grep -n YCbCr
```

and found what I believe to be the offending line

```
216:    "YCbCr": ('|u1', 4),
```

YCbCr images should be 3 channel, not 4.  I changed this to 3 and deleted the .pyc, but the code still crashed in the same way when it goes into the c code (core.fill with mode='YCbCr').  OK so I thought maybe the error worked its way into the build somehow, marked PIL for complete removal in package manager, downloaded the sources, dependencies, and modified that number 4 to 3, and after a bit of mucking around with paths was able to build PIL again, with all the selftests passing, then installing.  Unfortunately, still the same crash.  Now I'm at a loss at to what to do - I need YCbCr colour space support in PIL but can't fix the bug.

edit:  perhaps this can provide further insight, I've found that while `Image.new('YCbCr', (640,480))` did not crash in 10.10, it can be provoked to segfault by using `numpy.asarray(Image.new('YCbCr', (640,480)))`.  It all smells like a memory problem in some C-extension of numpy and/or PIL, or the way they are talking to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tracing down the source and it seems that it's the `strcpy()` at [libImaging/Storage.c:186](https://bitbucket.org/effbot/pil-117/src/10512a022230/libImaging/Storage.c#cl-186) that caused the buffer overflow. Further looking at the code and I found that `im->mode` is not big enough to hold `"YCbCr"`.

To solve this problem, just change [libImaging/Imaging.h:78](https://bitbucket.org/effbot/pil-117/src/f356a1f64271/libImaging/Imaging.h#cl-78) from `char mode[4+1];` to <strike>`char mode[4+2];`</strike>`char mode[6+1];` and recompile PIL.

For `numpy.asarray`, according to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797102/python-imaging-ycbcr-problems), I think its also a problem of PIL and your fix on `Image.py` should work.

edit: A patch for Fedora was commited before and it suggest changing to `char mode[6+1];` so the buffer is big enough to hold `"RGB;32"`.

OOT: If [Linus would see this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1124982/focus=1126216) he would definitely not accept my fix due to its magic..

Comment: I think the reason it's `char mode[4+1]` is to hold 4 characters plus a NULL terminator, so the correct fix would be `char mode[5+1]`. `[6+1]` would of course also work.

Comment: The better solution, however, probably would have been to avoid 'strcpy', in the case where future color modes longer than "YCbCr" or "RGB;32" need to be supported.

Comment: This bug is fixed in [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow), the PIL fork.