# PIL Image Convert from RGB to YCbCr Results in 4 Channels Instead of 3 and Behaves Like RGB

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Well, the title is pretty self explanatory. I have an image file that I want to separate into Y, Cb and Cr respectively. After opening the file, convert it from RGB (which is the default mode when opening an image file) into YCbCr and then turn it into an array using numpy.array(), it resulted in a 2D array with 4 channels, which is not I expected as according to the documentation in http://www.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/pil.pdf

Here is what I do in the interpreter:

```
ImageFile = Image.open('filePath', 'r')
ImageFile = ImageFile.convert('YCbCr')
ImageFileYCbCr = numpy.array(ImageFile)
ImageFileYCbCr
```

resulted in

```
array([[[103, 140, 133,  95],
    [140, 133,  91, 141],
    [132,  88, 141, 131],
    ..., 
    [129,  65, 146, 129],
    [ 64, 146, 130,  65],
    [146, 129,  64, 147]],

   [[129,  64, 147, 129],
    [ 62, 149, 130,  62],
    [149, 130,  62, 149],
    ...,
```

And when I separate it into its channels

```
ImageFileY = copy.deepcopy(ImageFileYCbCr) # to make a separate copy as array is immutable
ImageFileY[:,:,1] *= 0
ImageFileY[:,:,2] *= 0
ImageFileY[:,:,3] *= 0
ImageFileYOnly = Image.fromarray(ImageFileY)
ImageFileYOnly.show()
```

It resulted in a red color channel as if it is an RGB. Ho can I get the Y, Cb, Cr values respectively?

EDIT: Numpy version 1.3, Python 2.6 Linux Backtrack 5

Comment: _"... which is not I expected as according to the documentation in `http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j`..."_ That link brings me to an empty page. Looking at the `url=` parameter, I'm guessing you meant to link to [this pdf](http://www.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/pil.pdf)?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797102/python-imaging-ycbcr-problems which might help

Comment: Oh, you're right Kevin. I'll edit it. Thanks.

Comment: If I call `getbands()` on the image it returns `('Y', 'Cb', 'Cr')` and `getpixel((0,0))` returns a tuple with 3 members, which indicates 3 bands. The error must be in the conversion to `numpy`.

Comment: Any suggestion, Mark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2010-October/006526.html

It's an old bug with Numpy. To correct it

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import Image as im
>>> image = im.open('bush640x360.png')
>>> ycbcr = image.convert('YCbCr')

>>> B = numpy.ndarray((image.size[1], image.size[0], 3), 'u1', ycbcr.tostring())
>>> print B.shape
(360, 640, 3)
>>> im.fromarray(B[:,:,0], "L").show()
```

Comment: In later versions of PIL, (1.1.7, possibly earlier), `tostring()` has been removed, and so line 5 should be: `B = numpy.ndarray((image.size[1], image.size[0], 3), 'u1', ycbcr.tobytes())`

Answer (score 4):

FYI, for future people coming from Google:

**This seems to work now.**

For reference, I have Pillow 6.1.0 and numpy 1.17.0. Doing

```
img = np.array(Image.open(p).convert('YCbCr'))
```

gives the same as

```
img = Image.open(p).convert('YCbCr')
img = np.ndarray((img.size[1], img.size[0], 3), 'u1', img.tobytes())
```

and is not the same as RGB.